# Pyunit run all tests even when assert fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I Have a simple test like the following:

```
class TestAPIWrapper(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        assert 1==1, "Failed 1"
        assert 2==1, "Failed 2"
        assert 2==2, "Failed 3"
```

the way I execute this tests are the following:

```
python -m unittest my_test_file
```

What I got is, since the second assert fails, the test stops, and what I need is to run the tests until the end and get the assertions errors as they appear.

The idea behind this is I will have this test running every 6 hours on my server with crontab and I intend to send an email with all the error cases that test found.

Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't fail a single test more than once. The idea of "assert" is that it aborts the function if it fails.  You would have to separate your three asserts above into three separate test() methods (i.e. test_one(), test_two(), etc.) if you want to hit them all.  Also, you should use self.assertEqual() rather than the plain assert.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the (probably preferred) way of splitting your test into multiple functions with a single assert each is something like:

```
def test_one(self):
    failed = []
    if 1 != 1:
        failed.append("Failed 1")
    if 2 != 2:
        failed.append("Failed 2")
    # ...
    assert not failed, failed
```